# How can I set the picture associated with a node in a SmartArt graphic?

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-office, office-2010

SmartArt graphics can have pictures associated with the "nodes" (although this is only used by certain SmartArt templates). I know how to set the text of a node via VBA/VSTO automation, but I can't figure out how to set the picture.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this - if you've done any work in VBA with smartart this should make sense.

```
Dim oSALayout As SmartArtLayout
Dim QNode As SmartArtNode
Dim oShp As Shape

Set oSALayout = Application.SmartArtLayouts(91) 'reference to organization chart
Set oShp = Chart.Shapes.AddSmartArt(oSALayout, ileft, 2, iWidth, iHeight)    
Set QNode = oShp.SmartArt.AllNodes.Add

...

' note that there may be more than one shape associated with each node, I found that those org chart/smart art layouts with a specific "picture box" typically use Shapes.Item(2) 

With QNode.Shapes.Item(1).Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .UserPicture "c:\somepath\picture.jpg"
    .TextureTile = msoFalse
End With
```

hope that makes sense!

Comment: how about clipboard