# Adding photo to OrgChart (smartart layout 98)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This is so simple question that I am quite embarrassed to ask. I would like to add photo to org chart in PowerPoint. I am using `SmartArtLayout(98)`, this is the kind of `orgchart` with a slot for image. I have tried reach this slot following `IntelliSense` suggestion but it led me nowhere. 
I have been trying to google for any `object model` for this specific shape but I am unable to find anything. Could you help? I guess it must be something after:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).SmartArt.Nodes(1).
```

but what?
I have tried even to draw org chart in Excel and record a macro, however, inserting a photo were not recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157999/how-can-i-set-the-picture-associated-with-a-node-in-a-smartart-graphic):

SmartArtNode.Shapes.Item(1).Fill.UserPicture "c:\somepath\picture.jpg"

E.g.

```
With QNode.Shapes.Item(1).Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .UserPicture "c:\somepath\picture.jpg"
    .TextureTile = msoFalse
End With
```

I think you need to do some fiddling the following idea does show the image only in the slot

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim oSALayout As SmartArtLayout
Dim myNode As SmartArtNode
Dim oShp As Shape

Set oSALayout = Application.SmartArtLayouts(98)

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).SmartArt.Layout = oSALayout

Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3)

Set myNode = oShp.SmartArt.AllNodes.Add

With myNode.Shapes(2).Fill

    .UserPicture "C:\Users\User\Desktop\XmasTree.jpg"

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: This put image in the background of the shape. I would like it in the Node, in the dedicated slot.

Comment: I think is doable just need to do some fiddling. For example, the following also insert into the dedicated slot   With myNode.Shapes.Fill : .UserPicture "C:\Users\me\Desktop\XmasTree.jpg"    but need to mess around with background to make not visible if possible.

Comment: The answer in my opinion is correct. In reference to your initial code it looks like this: `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).SmartArt.Nodes(1).Shapes(1).Fill.UserPicture "m:\Documents\...full...path...to ...file.jpg"`. **Tried and tested.** If not working add more information to your question.

Comment: Answer that I can see above is not correct. I have seen correct answer here, but it was edited out, I don't know for what reason. I'm waiting for it back to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I have put back. Just it was working for me then wasn't so i deleted as i can't reproduce with confidence am a little concerned about posting. Feedback welcomed and i will edit answer.

Comment: So, the clue is that picture slot is available as TheNode.Shapes(2). Thank you very much.